# How to call a function after a fadeOut() on many elements

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
$('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(500, function () {
    alert("Now all '.hotel_photo_select are hidden'");
});
```

and I'd like to call that alert only when **ALL** `.hotel_photo_select` are fadeOuted (so, Hidden).

How can I do it? With my code the alert is called after the first element is fadeout...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method for this (the doc page has a good example for this).

> The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is
> resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection,
> queued or not, have ended.

Applied to your example should be something like this:

```
$.when(
    $('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(500)
).done(function() {

    alert("Now all '.hotel_photo_select are hidden'");

});
```

OR

```js
$('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(500)
    .promise().done(function() {
        alert('Got this far!');
    });
```

Comment: How are you using the .promise() here?

Comment: Here is the promise() version:     $('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
        alert("Now all '.hotel_photo_select are hidden'");
    });

Answer (score 5):

```
$(element).fadeOut(duration, onComplete)
```

Example:

```
$('#box').fadeOut(400, () => { console.log('Fade effect is done') })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please add a short explanation of the syntax and an example for the beginners who stumble into your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery `$.when().then()` functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // using When & then methods.
  $.when($('.box').fadeOut())
   .then(function(){
      alert("All Boxes : Faded Out.");
   });
});
```

```css
.box{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calling Alert After fadeOut</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">Box 1</div> <br />
    <div class="box">Box 2</div> <br />
    <div class="box">Box 3</div> <br />
    <div class="box">Box 4</div> <br />
    <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```