# Exit function only when fadeOut has finished in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that is called on a click event to hide an overlay. This calls the jQuery `fadeOut` method with a time of 750 - see below.

```
function Hide_Site_Overlay() {
    $('#site_overlay,#site_overlay_background').fadeOut(750, function(){
        //do other stuff
    });
}
```

But, in the click event handler, I follow this call with another - e.g.

```
onclick="Hide_Site_Overlay(); Show_Next_Overlay();"
```

How can I make sure the code waits for the hide to finish before the show starts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function after a fadeOut() on many elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259608/how-to-call-a-function-after-a-fadeout-on-many-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Provide the second function to the first as a callback to be executed when the `fadeOut` has completed. Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Hide_Site_Overlay(Show_Next_Overlay);">Foo</a>
```

```js
function Hide_Site_Overlay(callback) {
    $('#site_overlay,#site_overlay_background').fadeOut(750, function(){
        //do other stuff

        callback && callback(); // only make the callback if one was provided
    });
}
```

Or, better still, would be to remove the outdated and ugly `onclick` attributes from your HTML and use JS to hookup your events:

```
<a href="#" class="overlay-control">Foo</a>
```

```js
$('.overlay-control').click(function() {
    Hide_Site_Overlay(Show_Next_Overlay);
});
```

If the callback function has properties, you would just need to provide them in the call:

```
callback && callback(2, 'divLoginOverlay');
```

Comment: They still would be - you're only passing the reference to the function.

Comment: How do I pass this if the Show function needs variables - e.g. Show_Site_Overlay(2, 'divLoginOverlay');?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to move `Show_Next_Overlay()` call to the `Hide_Site_Overlay` function. Example code:

```
function Hide_Site_Overlay() {
    $('#site_overlay,#site_overlay_background').fadeOut(750, function(){
        //do other stuff
        Show_Next_Overlay();
    });
}
```

Otherwise you can change the `Hide_Site_Overlay` function, so it takes a callback as argument and executes it when fadeOut has finished. Example code:

```
function Hide_Site_Overlay(callback) {
    $('#site_overlay,#site_overlay_background').fadeOut(750, function(){
        //do other stuff
        if (typeof callback == "function")
          callback();
    });
}
```

You can also use `setTimeout` function, for example:

```
onclick="Hide_Site_Overlay(); setTimeout(Show_Next_Overlay, 750);"
```