# How can I make this slideshow to keep playing itself?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I haven't had much experience with jquery but just about managed to code the following to create a image slideshow.

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
$('.fadein .fadein1').delay (10000).fadeOut(400);
$('.fadein .fadein2').delay(10000).fadeIn(400).delay (10000).fadeOut (400);
$('.fadein .fadein3').delay(20000).fadeIn(400).delay (10000).fadeOut(400);
```

My problem now is that the last image obviously fades out and doesn't return back to the starting image. So my question is what can I add/change to rectify this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function after a fadeOut() on many elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259608/how-to-call-a-function-after-a-fadeout-on-many-elements)

Comment: The answer in the linked duplicate shows how you could call a function once the `fadeOut` completes. So you need to wrap your code into a function, and call that after the very last `fadeOut` completes.

Answer (score -1):

you can try `$('.fadein .fadein1').delay (10000).fadeToggle();`